# Buttons and Labels Not in Place

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am asking perhaps one of the easiest questions lol but just could not figure it out.

I have some view controllers created based on the screen size of iPhone 7, but when I change devices to iPhone 7plus and iPhoneSE, my labels and buttons were all misplaced...

I have uploaded what they look like in different devices, can somebody please help?

[WhatItLooksLikeOniPhone7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5G96.png)

[WhatItLooksLikeOniPhoneSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Czkx.png)

Comment: You need to learn Autolayout and apply constraints on these buttons and labels to make them correct for various screen sizes.

Comment: You must use auto layout its the easiest way to do that

Comment: Where's your source code?  What are your layout constraints?  There's no way to say what's wrong without knowing what you're doing now.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the UI elements at a defined place you need to something that will keep the elements at their position. And hence you need to use autolayout.
Autolayout is basically a constraint based system which  will layout the ui elements.
There are many tutorials available.