# UIView button not visible on iPhone 5 despite constraints

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, uistoryboard, iphone-5

I have a UIViewController with a next button that appears after a click on another UI element.

[image]
This works perfect on any iPhone above iPhone5S. The next button has a constraint with a value of 20 from the bottom. On top of the View, I added a SKView using this code :

```
        // Create frame for SKView
        let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let SKheight = (bounds.size.height) - 200
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 140, width: bounds.size.width, height: SKheight)
        skView = SKView(frame: frame)
        view.addSubview(skView)

        // Create BubbleScene and place it on SKView
        floatingCollectionScene = BubblesScene(size: frame.size)
        skView.presentScene(floatingCollectionScene)
```

The SKHeight is the height of the screen of the device used minus 200. This because I want to start it at a height of 140(so that the text on top of the VC is still visible). Normally this would give me a whitespace of 60px heigh at the bottom. This works fine on the iPhone 7 / Plus but on smaller versions like the iPhone 5 I don't see the next button. I guess that the skView is overlapping it somehow..?

Any ideas? 
Thanks!!

Comment: I think your problem is you are going off of the screen size.  If you are using constraints then you should not be doing this.  In fact, what you are doing could all be done in the storyboard so that you do not have to play guessing games like this

Comment: Any idea how to do this on the storyboard?

Comment: I do, but to explain it in SO is a bit tough,  if you send me your project,  I will setup the storyboard for you, and you can learn by playing around with what I did

Comment: That would be great! Thanks !! This is the link to my storyboard : https://www.dropbox.com/s/bevzdq7uoou3iaw/Main.storyboard?dl=0

Comment: see here for refernce, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44870709/buttons-and-labels-not-in-place/44871820#44871820

Comment: what view controller is this?

Comment: https://expirebox.com/files/f38236c47a3fb8b60e8fc38e0f35d0b5.storyboard  Take a look at how I made the constraints.  You seem to have some kind of understanding of how it works.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon it is the initial viewcontroller. Do you see it?

Comment: Thanks for the file @Knight0fDragon ! don't see any changes though :(

Comment: are you sure,  you should see a new child view, with a few constraints

Comment: Oh okay sorry missed that. Yes I see a new StackView inside the existing stackview. What are the next steps?

Comment: that should be all you need,  delete your code that is posted here, and reference that SKView when you need it

Comment: Oh okay, but if i delete that code, how will my skview be added? And how will it know its dimensions?